Android Studio: New library catalogue - how to exclude a component
In Android Studio (Koala) and in the app's build file, I'm trying to implement a library but exclude a group/component of it. I tried multiple ways to do it, but it's not working for me.

implementation(libs.googleApiClientAndroid,) {
    exclude("org.apache.httpcomponents")
}


This is my current implementation snippet. But the exclude is wrong. I have the googleApiClientAndroid set up in the libs.versions.toml file.

There is no support yet for version catalog references and exclude blocks.
See here.
You need to write the dependency in a string for it to work:
implementation("this.is:a-lib:1.2.3") {
    exclude(group = "another.lib", module = "that-i-do-not-want")
}


so it's basically just writing it the previous way, like this:
        exclude(group = "org.apache.httpcomponents", module = "httpclient")
     }```

? That's very annoying, but thank you.
